# Remove unwanted text from link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello friends i want to make a function that remove specific group of words from input link before doing search :

i got this coding :

**jquery :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function GetIdinfo() {
            var q = document.getElementById("graph").value;
            window.open("http://graph.facebook.com/" + q,"", "width=500px, height=300px");
        }
    </script>
```

**HTML :**

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<input id="graph" type="text" name="q" size="20" placeholder="Guru.of.Fun or 100XXXX"/></td>
<input type="button" name="graph" value="Get Facebook Data" class="submit" onclick="GetIdinfo()" />
```

and now i want to get some help to remove `https://graph.facebook.com/` and only read text after back slash `/` **for example :**

```
100008622 from full link https://www.facebook.com/100008622
```

- if any user enter in search text area..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.split().pop()`:

```
var url = document.getElementById("graph").value;
var value = url.split('/').pop();
```

---

Here the `.split()` makes an array out of the url and `.pop()` returns the last value in the array.

---

You can see the test here.

```js
var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/100008622';
var value = url.split('/').pop();
alert(value)
```

Comment: i would like to repeat that what i'm asking for : `if user type full address in search box then coding pick text after **https://www.facebook.com/**`

Comment: Further more @Jai i'm learner so would you please refer me any site with tutorials, where i can learn `new row in table by clicking new and then save add text in row`
thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex

```
var regex = /\d+/g;
var string = "https://www.facebook.com/100008622";//window.location.href you can use directly this;
var matches = string.match(regex);  
alert(matches);
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/somnath_k/yzzjnfsk/)

Comment: Further more @Somnath i'm learner so would you please refer me any site with tutorials, where i can learn `new row in table by clicking new and then save add text in row`
thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Regex replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function

```
var str = "https://www.facebook.com/100008622";
str.replace(/https:\/\/www.facebook.com\//i, "");
```